# Same frameworks/libraries on Node.js and Sproutcore

Tags: javascript, node.js, sproutcore

I am using Node.js and Sproutcore.

My goal is to use same frameworks/libraries as much as possible on both sides so I don't have to learn two things to accomplish one thing.

Do you know libraries/frameworks that work on both ends (testing, http requests, javascript extensions etc)

Comment: its possible. Just port CommonJS to the browser. I'm working on verbatim code re-use between the browser & node.js but based on backbonejs instead because thats a lot more lightweight. You of course have to restrict yourself to a useful subset. I'm only copying the browser/node agnostic bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"so I don't have to learn two things to accomplish one thing" You will need to learn both. I think maybe YUI is something you should look into. YUI will help you build your **logic/business**  for both client and server.

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/